# Java Stream interface map function argument types

Tags: java, dictionary, java-stream

The map function in the Stream interface is defined like this:

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper)
```

with the Function argument list consistent with Function intefaces's own specification

```
Interface Function<T,R>
```

with the method being

```
R apply(T t)
```

meaning it takes a T but returns an R. But I am running this code

```
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.function.*;

public class T3 {
    public static void main(String...args){
        mapTest();        
    }    
    static void mapTest(){
        Stream<String> s = Stream.of("monkey", "gorilla", "bonobo");
        s.map(String::length).forEach(System.out::print); // 676        
    }
}
```

and wondering, how come it works but the argument types don't *seem* to match up?
There's no easy way of explaining it, but my understanding is a Function is supposed to take input of type T and return type R. And when it's used in the stream it's taking input of type String and returning type int. (ie string.length()). But Stream.map is typed to return the **same type** as the stream (ie R, in this case String ie NOT an int):  `<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper)`.
So what's going on here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When a function has no parameters (such as ``length``), the function is invoked on current stream element. Which means your ``map(String::length)`` is the same as writing ``map(s-> s.length())``.

Comment: "But Stream.map is typed to return the same type as the stream" - that is not correct. The original stream delivers instances of T (hence ``apply(T t)``) and returns a stream of R instances (because each call to ``apply`` returns an R).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `map`-method you are invoking on the `Stream` takes a `mapper` with the type `Function<? super T, ? extends R>`. So there are two generic types here: `T` and `R`.
`T` is the element type of the processed stream.
`R`  is according to the API

> The element type of the new stream

Your `mapper` takes a `String` and returns its `String.length()`. The return type of `String.length()` is an `int`. This is the type of the elements of the resulting stream. So your mapper is typed

```
Function<? super String, ? extends Integer>
```

as the `int` is autoboxed to `Integer`.

Answer (score 2):

To Understand it let's look at the lengh function.

[image]

So to this function to work it need an object of String type and no parameters to be called. It will return than a int primitive that could be wrapped in a Integer.

So what if we could transform it in a Function? We would need an parameter o String to serve as a object and a Return of Integer, so the next code will work:

[image]

The map function is used to apply some kind of computation over the elements of a list in the same order and return the result. You can find more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)).

So now it's clear that the premise:

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper)
```

Will work with:

```
Stream<String> s = Stream.of("monkey", "gorilla", "bonobo");
s.map(String::length).forEach(System.out::print); // 676
```

If you wanted to recreate the Function you should do something like this:

```
Function<String, Integer> z = (s) -> s.length();
```

Both "i" and "z" will do the same, and that's why your code works.